# How to set uibinder text from xml

Tags: xml, gwt, uibinder

I have HTMLPanel, and I want to set as text there some XML-file content. How I can do this? Maybe using `<ui:with type="com.blablblba.Filename.xml" field="conent"/>` ?

For example : I have Widget.ui.xml 
And it contains some code like

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
             xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui"
                 >
    <ui:style>
    </ui:style>

    <g:VerticalPanel spacing="10">
        <panel:ContentPanel collapsible="true" height="300px" width="150px"></panel:ContentPanel>
        <panel:ContentPanel width="100%">
            <g:HTMLPanel ui:field="xmlInfo">
            </g:HTMLPanel>
        </panel:ContentPanel>
    </g:VerticalPanel>

</ui:UiBinder>
```

And I want to display this code on another widget as a text using UiBinder

Comment: what do you want to achieve exactly. can you provide your Ui binder code with which you need help

Comment: added example of what I want

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried this approach, but I think it might work.

Create a [TextResource](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#TextResource) file (i.e. myTextFile).

Declare it in UiBinder:

```
<ui:with field="content" type="com.blablblba.myTextFile" />
```

Then use it like:

```
<g:HTMLPanel ui:field="xmlInfo">
    <ui:text from="{content.getText}" />
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can do that directly. You will need to make use of `RequestBuilder`

```
new RequestBuilder(Method.GET, "xmlPath").sendRequest("", new RequestCallback() {
  @Override
  public void onResponseReceived(Request req, Response resp) {
    String text = resp.getText();
    // do stuff with the text
  }

  @Override
  public void onError(Request res, Throwable throwable) {
    // handle errors
  }
});
```

Comment: emm... I can get text as String much easier - via TextResource.getText()